# how to parse post data back into original format in golang?

Tags: go

Ok, i think this question is NOT a question in others web programming language like php, python.

but i met this question in golang and confused what is the best way to convert the post raw data back into it's original format.

and here is a sample.

**1** original representation is an array consists of map:

```
photo[1][tags]{id: 1, direction:1, x: 1.0, y: 2, word: 'pull'}
photo[1][tags]{id: 2, direction:0, x: 2.0, y: 1.1, word: 'fi'}
```

> process handler

```
func testPostData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error{
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
    data := r.ParseMultipartForm.Value
    fmt.Println(data)
}

**2** outputs in console
map[photo[1][tags][][direction]:[0]
    photo[1][tags][][word]:[fi]
    photo[1][tags][][x]:[1.1]
    photo[1][tags][][id]:[2]]
```

i'm a newbie to golang, so i think there is a way to help to convert **data** back to its original representation, here is convert 2 back to 1

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? For example, what is _post raw data_ you are talking about, and in which format you want to convert it back.  And from where it is parsing this data?

Comment: I agree that this question needs more clarification. For one, from where are you getting those different representations? You've printed out the original representation, and then the result parsed by golang: How did you arrive at those values? I'm not aware of anything in Go that prints results the way you have.

Comment: thanks, how to convert the post data back to its original representation, in my sample is convert 2 back to 1

Comment: POST data often arrives URL-encoded, like `id=1&direction=1&x=1.0`, or JSON-encoded like `[{"id":1,"direction":1},{"id":2,"direction":0}]` (note the quotes, and `[]` for the list). Something like `Printf` will print data in yet another format that's designed more for human viewing than decoding, and the original isn't always recoverable from the `Printf`'d output. It *may* be your "1" above is a `Printf` of some Go structs, and if so that's probably not really the original format of the POST data. For debugging, `r.Body.Read()` would get you the raw POST data, just to see what format it's in.

Comment: I wonder if the original format is like `photo[1][tags][][x]=1.1&photo[1][tags][][id]=2`, which would lead to a map like your #2 coming from `r.MultipartForm.Values`. That's a peculiar format, but I've seen key names like `person[name]` from some frameworks. As an alternative to `r.Body.Read()`, you might be able to see information about posted data in the Network tab of your browser's development tools.

Comment: @twotwotwo thanks, for example i post a map in ios like :
`content =    [ {
            id = 547;
            sort = 1;
            tags =  ( {
                    x = "0.35";
                    y = "0.678125";
                })
        },
        {name = value;
            id = 0;
            sort = 2;
            type = text;
        }]`
and now how convert  it back to original representation in golang?

Comment: I'd recommend using a common format like [JSON](http://godoc.org/encoding/json) to send the data to Go and to send it back. The format in your comment might be Swift source or you see when you print something out for debugging, but as far as I know isn't a well-known format for sending data over the Internet between servers in different languages.